# Read/Write file causing errors. (javaScript & C++)

Tags: javascript, c++, xml, runtime-error

I have a piece of javaScript that works (alongside html) to produce the GUI for a program written in C++. The program has to run for a long time (Sometimes 14/15 days, without monitoring).

The C++ and javaScript communicate by writing to/reading from a XML file.

After running the program for over 24 hours at a time, I've noticed the occasional javaScript error appearing 'someArray[...].name' is null or not an object.

Now: These are all arrays that are filled with information taken from the XML file, written by the C++. The contents of these arrays are refreshed every few seconds (To update information in the GUI 'live').

Question is: Could these errors be caused by an access/timer problem as in --> The javaScript starts reading a line from the XML just as the C++ swoops in and rewrites that line. Therefore information is parsed into the javaScript arrays with some illegal characters (etc) which when accessed throws the errors?

Hope that all makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: can you give us the exact error.

Comment: error: ['properties[...].name' is null or not an object] and that from a line that reads:   `for (var i=0; i<properties.length; i++) {
  if (properties[i].name == name) {
   return properties[i].value;
  }
 }`

Comment: If you can't run a debugger then do the following: for(int i = 0, length = properties.length; i++) { console.log('index ' + i + ' value: ' + properties[i]) }. I have the impresion that you store strings or numbers in that array; or you might even accidentally store null values

Comment: Right! I think I've got it. First, thank you both, Both very helpful. My solution was a simply test function `function realValue(obj){
 var type = typeof obj;
 if(type !== "null" && type !== "undefined") {
  return obj;
 } else {
  $("*").each(function(){$(this).css("background",randomColour());});
  return "";
 }
}`. I called that every time a value is taken from the XML file. Going to have to run the code now for acouple days to make sure it works. Thanks team.

Comment: Just for a note: the randomColour() function is just so I know I've caught something. It applies a random colour to every element in the DOM. Very useful.

Comment: You could probably change your if statement to something like this: if(obj){}. The problem with the typeOf is that it returns "object" if the value of obj is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion seems to provide a plausible explanation of what's happening.
You're probably seeing a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

To fix it, you could implement a synchronization mechanism between C++ and JS.
The simplest form of sync I can think of is creating a second file each time C++ writes to your main XML file (this file acts as a lock). JS waits for the lock file to disappear before reading the XML. The same is done on the C++ side.

Sample code:

**C++**:

```
while(programRunning) {
    do stuff;
    // Now it's time to write XML
    while("lockCpp.txt" exists)
        ;  // Do nothing, JS is reading
    create file "lockJS.txt";
    write to xml;
    delete file "lockJS.txt";
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
while(programRunning) {
    do stuff;
    // Now it's time to read XML
    while("lockJS.txt" exists)
        ;  // Do nothing
    create file "lockCpp.txt";
    read xml;
    delete file "lockCpp.txt";
}
```

This should in practice eliminate race conditions (though some are theoretically, possible, but unlikely).

Should JS not be allowed to *write* to the file system, then you could remove one of the lock files (*lockCpp.txt*) and, if the reading on the JS side is normally faster then the writing, it should still eliminate most conflicts.

**EDIT after comment:**

If you only have access to JS, you could check that the XML document is complete when reading, e.g. the root element is correcly matched by a `</rootElementName>` at the end.
That will ensure the file write is complete *provided C++ doesn't do writes at random locations, but always rewrites the whole document*.

Another route would be checking the file is not changing over time. If C++ only sporadically writes to XML, you can read it a few times over a few, say, seconds, and, if unchanged, use the read value. If changed, keep waiting.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Mau! 'Race condition' -> Thats the line I was looking for. I'm a placement industry student and only have access to the javaScript, so any solution I'm afraid will have to be through that end of the code. (However, I'm going to suggest your reply). Currently trying to put conditions in to check the XML while its parsed into the javaScript. Hoping that might do the trick.

Comment: Oooo! I like the idea of checking the root element... I will try that now.